# Express Server Not Handling Simultaneous API Calls Asynchroniously (Waiting for old call to resolve)

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am creating my first web application using the MEVN stack (MongoDb, Express, VueJS, Node). As far as I can tell from research, functions in my node server.js file are all async by default, but every time I make a request (POST/GET whatever) to the API, it halts the backend until that function has resolved. I need users who use the website to be able to send GET requests to the site while another user is uploading info to the DB for instance with a POST request in another function. Currently it just halts all calls until the first one resolves. I am testing by going to /test on my server with a 5 second wait, while simultaneously making a call to /api in Postman. The Postman request just hangs until the /test function resolves. I'm sure this is a novice issue, but why is this not functioning asynchronously? I have pasted the head from my server.js below

```
// Importing required modules

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const multer = require('multer');
const hashlips = require('./src/main.js')
const fs = require('fs-extra');

// parse env variables
require('dotenv').config();

require("./helpers/db/mongodb.js")();

// Configuring port
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

//configure express
const app = express();

// Configure middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}, { limit: '10mb' }));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/'));

// Defining route middleware
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

//routes
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
    res.send("<h3>Express Server")
})
```

Here' is my api.js

```
const express = require('express');

const {
  //init CRUD
  createData,
  readData,
  updateData,
  deleteData,
  deleteAllData,
  //init register login
  registerNewUser,
  loginUser,
  getUserDetails,
  //init collection saving
  createCollection,
  readCollectionData,
  deleteAllCollections,
  deleteCollection,
  updateCollection,
} = require('../controllers/user_controller');

const auth = require('../config/auth')

const router = express.Router();

router
  .put("/collection", createCollection)
  .put("/collectionu", updateCollection)
  .post("/", createData)
  .post("/register", registerNewUser)
  .post("/login", loginUser)
  .get("/collection", readCollectionData)
  .get("/me", auth, getUserDetails)
  .get('/', readData)
  .put('/:id', updateData)
  .delete('/deletecollections', deleteAllCollections)
  .delete('/deleteall', deleteAllData)
  .delete('/deletecollection/:id', auth, deleteCollection)
  .delete('/:id', deleteData);

module.exports = router;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Idk if it's helpful but here's my --trace-sync-io stack trace:

```
(node:62551) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at pbkdf2Sync (node:internal/crypto/pbkdf2:80:37)
    at HI (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/scram.js:245:31)
    at continueScramConversation (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/scram.js:138:28)
    at /home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/scram.js:90:9
    at onMessage (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:222:9)
    at /home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:63:60
    at emit (node:events:394:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20)
    at _write (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
Connected to MongoDB
(node:62551) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at randomFillSync (node:internal/crypto/random:137:19)
    at randomBytes (node:internal/crypto/random:99:5)
    at uuidV4 (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:439:27)
    at ServerSession (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sessions.js:541:62)
    at acquire (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sessions.js:619:16)
    at get serverSession (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sessions.js:94:46)
    at applySession (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sessions.js:670:35)
    at command (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:278:53)
    at /home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/server.js:210:18
    at /home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:271:13
(node:62551) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at randomFillSync (node:internal/crypto/random:137:19)
    at randomBytes (node:internal/crypto/random:99:5)
    at ObjectId.generate (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/bson/lib/objectid.js:145:54)
    at ObjectId (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/bson/lib/objectid.js:47:34)
    at NativeCollection.<computed> (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:84:18)
    at create (/home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1803:22)
    at /home/zach/Documents/WebProjects/mevn/ezmode/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1764:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Comment: It should be `app.get('/test', async (req, res) => { ... }` but that's probably not going to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you make another test-endpoint that is not involved with mongo and check if it blocks as well?

Comment: Hmm, yeah it didn't block when I made a new endpoint called Test2, loaded fine then the promise on the test1 finished normally afterwards.
EDIT: God bless, i was missing async call to the mongoose method in user_controller.js. Thanks!

Changed "const readData = (req, res) => {
 User.find()"

to

"const readData = async (req, res) => {
  await User.find()"

Comment: Great you figured it out, happy to help :)